# Psql querying json arrays

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

The json that I store in postgres db has the following structure. I need to fetch the rows in which all the domains of email is 'gmail.com'

Row1:

```
{
   "student_id": "123",
   "name": "foo",
   "emails":[
      {
        "id": "777",
        "domain": "gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "id": "888",
        "domain": "gmail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Row2:

```
{
   "student_ id": "345",
   "name": "booo",
   "emails":[
      {
        "id": "444",
        "domain": "gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "id": "555",
        "domain": "yahoo.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

In this case, my result should only be the student with student_id 123 i.e. row 1. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the table name is `student` and the field name, holding the json data, is `data`.

```
WITH
  mail_domain AS (
    SELECT
      (data->'student_id')::text AS student_id,
      (JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(data->'emails')->'domain')::text AS domain
    FROM
      student),

  selected_student AS (
    SELECT
      student_id
    FROM
      mail_domain
    WHERE
      domain = '"gmail.com"'

    EXCEPT

    SELECT
      student_id
    FROM
      mail_domain
    WHERE
      domain != '"gmail.com"')

SELECT
  *
FROM
  student
WHERE
  (data->'student_id')::text IN (
    SELECT
      student_id
    FROM
      selected_student);
```